# Find infos from .ipa file

Tags: ios, ipa

Hi I want to get infos from an .ipa file (apple application file). Is there an equivalent of the AndroidManifest.xml file in Android with all the informations from an app ?

How can I access the itunes detail page ([https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pokémon-go/id1094591345?mt=8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pok%C3%A9mon-go/id1094591345?mt=8)) if I only have the .ipa file ?

I want to create a package with the .ipa file and a json with all the informations I can find.

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. This may be better suited for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .IPA file is just a zip file of the application .. you can unzip it.

It should contain info.plist files which have more information about the application.

The plist can be in xml format or in some binary format.. there are for example python libraries to read the binary plist format. (for example https://github.com/farcaller/bplist-python)

Comment: macOS contains the [plutil](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Plutil) command line utility, which can be used to convert binary plists into xml. `plutil -convert binary1 file.plist`